# Check if indexed field exists

Tags: hibernate-search, hibernate-search-6

I'm trying to migrate my application from hibernate search 5 to 6. What I noticed in version 6 is that a field validation is added and you can't search on fields that doesn't exists in the index. Unfortunately I have business logic that relied on that. Is there a way to access ElasticsearchIndexModel class(as far as I can see in this class is the fields state) and check if a specific field exists? Or is there any way to do that at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [metamodel API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-mapping-inspect).

Something like this should work:

```java
<T> boolean isSearchable(SearchMapping mapping, Class<T> entityClass,
        String fieldPath) {
    SearchIndexedEntity<T> entity = mapping.indexedEntity( entityClass ); 
    IndexDescriptor index = bookEntity.indexManager().descriptor();
    Optional<IndexFieldDescriptor> fieldOptional = index.field(fieldPath)
    if (!fieldOptional.isPresent()) {
        return false;
    }
    IndexFieldDescriptor field = fieldOptional.get();
    return field.isValueField() && field.toValueField().type().searchable();
}
```

You can access the `SearchMapping` this way:

```java
SearchMapping mapping = Search.mapping( entityManagerFactory );
```

Or:

```java
SearchMapping mapping = Search.mapping( entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory() );
```

Or in Quarkus, you can simply [have it injected](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-search-orm-elasticsearch#multiple-persistence-units-attaching-cdi) into your beans:

```java
public class MyBean {
    @Inject
    SearchMapping mapping;


    ...
}
```